# Is there anywhere to find statistics on how many DNS servers are still vulnerable to the Kaminsky DNS Vulnerability?

Tags: domain-name-system, security

I just started reading about this vulnerability and I was curious if it is still a wide spread problem even though it was found 2 years ago.  Does anyone know of anywhere that has reliable statistics on how wide spread this problem is currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a recent graph I saw presented at the last IETF meeting from the Austrian registry around 30% of the clients they see still haven't got proper source port and/or query ID randomisation.

The slides are available [here](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/78/slides/dnsop-4.pdf).

Comment: Interesting, please do share it when you find it.